# Exclude thrift generated files from javadoc

Tags: java, gradle, thrift

My build.gradle has the following task which is pretty standard.

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
```

However I keep getting javadoc lint errors for my thrift generated files.  Adding an exclude like `exclude '**/gen-java/**'` to the end of a task does not seem to work.  How can i tell this gradle task to stop looking at my thrift-generated java files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tweak the `javadoc` task added by the `java` plugin

```
javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava.matching {
       exclude '**/gen-java/**'
    }
}
```

If you're publishing javadoc & sources jars you might be interested in the [nebula.javadoc-jar](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin#nebulajavadoc-jar) and [nebula.source-jar](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin#nebulasource-jar) plugins which save a bit of boilerplate each time in your build scripts

Comment: After further experimenting the above did not work for me, but adding excludes that matched the package naming structure did work.  Do all maven excludes expect you to do this?

Comment: Ah, it sounds like `gen-java` is not under `src/main/java` in which case you could use `javadoc { source = fileTree('src/main/java') }`. The javadoc task's `source` property is of type `FileCollection`, there's many wonderful ways to create one of these